# Is a group structure is need for this analysis

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

We know that $ℤ/nℤ$ is a finite set, then it is possible to find a bijection $$θ:ℤ/nℤ→T={1,2,...,n}$$ where $T$ is a finite part of natural numbers ℕ.

Let us consider the set $G=ℤ^{r}×ℤ/nℤ$, (cartesian product of two sets) ($r$ is a finite intger) then any element in $G$ can be considered as the *ordered pair* $((a₁,a₂,...,a_{r}),b)$ where $b$ is an equivalent class in $ℤ/nℤ$.

We can find a bijection $$ψ:ℤ^{r}×ℤ/nℤ→ℤ^{r}×T$$ by using the bijection $θ$. Hence any element in $ℤ^{r}×ℤ/nℤ$ can be **identified uniquely** by an element of the set $ℤ^{r}×T$. My **question** is: Is a group structure is need for this analysis, or the proof by this way is correct and do not requires any **binary operations** defined on $ℤ^{r}×ℤ/nℤ$ and $ℤ^{r}×T $?.

Comment: Well, you already did the analysis. Did your analysis use the group structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group structure is only needed to define 
$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$

and show that it is finite of order $n$.

Then it is all set theory - if $A,A'$ are finite with $n$ elements
then there exist a bijection 
$$
\varphi:A\to A'
$$

and for any other set $B$ there is a bijection 
$$
B\times A\to B\times A'
$$

For example - there is one given by 
$$
(b,a)\to(b,\varphi(a))
$$

Note: Just to here $A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},A'=\{1,...,n\},B=\mathbb{Z}^{r}$